# How to set another page as default page in ASPNET BOILERPLATE MVC5?

Tags: asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying change default page when I start my app, but I can't do it. When I start the first page is "Account/Login", but I need it changes to other pages.

In project web I'm doing this: * HomeController: Add HomePage actionResult * View/Home: Add View to Home with name HomePage

In app_start/routeconfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute( name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "HomePage", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

Also, i changed the properties of web project to specify page: Home/Homepage, but it's not working

Results in both options arent work

Template: Boilerplate with ASP.NET MVC 5 + Zero Module

i'm new with abp.

Comment: So you want to see a different page before you login? Do you even want to login? Basically on your home page there is a piece of functionality (for example the part that shows your login name) that requires you to login. If you remove all security requirements from your home page it won't ask to login.

Comment: Exactly, i want to see a different page before login. I wanna a HomePage and there i pretend to put a button to login. Okey, i'm gonna do that and comment results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's better to use a different controller for anonymous actions. Create a new controller called WelcomeController. Do not add a AbpMvcAuthroize attribute. Then set your default route as Welcome/Index.

Answer (score 1):

In [HomeController.cs](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/blob/51bb80104f8aeeaf5e52fb488134b5d9605f3d4d/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.WebMpa/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L6), comment out (or remove) the `[AbpMvcAuthorize]` attribute:

```
// [AbpMvcAuthorize]
public class HomeController : AbpProjectNameControllerBase
```

You can apply `[AllowAnonymous]` for specific actions to suppress authentication/authorization:

```
[AbpMvcAuthorize]
public class HomeController : AbpProjectNameControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult HomePage()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

See the documentation on [MVC Controllers](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/MVC-Controllers#authorization).